# using boost::python::list as return value need increase ob_refcnt?

Tags: boost-python

I am trying my best to find memory leaks in a very important module in our project and got a code snippet like this:

```
PyObject* python_func( const char* str )
{
       ..........................

    boost::python::list obj;
    obj.append(str);
    obj.ptr()->ob_refcnt++;  //this is necessary??
    return obj.ptr();
}
```

I am confused about this line: `obj.ptr()->ob_refcnt++;`

I think ob_refcnt is maintained by python internally for gc, we can't operate it so obviously cause this will lead to memory leaks, on the other hand, obj is going to leave its scope, I am not sure if boost::python::list deconstructor will decrease ob_refcnt, if that's true, remove that line, the resource obj hold would be released, that will lead to a crash.

So my question is whether `obj.ptr()->ob_refcnt++;` is necessary, and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the code increases the reference count is that `python_func` is intended to return a *new reference* to the object. (A new reference is one that has the reference count already increased -- returning a new reference allows the function to create new objects, such as a new list in this case.) On the other hand, the `ptr()` member function returns a *borrowed reference* to the object.

As you correctly surmised, if the code failed to increase the reference count of the borrowed reference, the destructor of `boost::python::list` would decrease the reference count and the returned object would be invalid.

Note that you should never directly access the `ob_refcnt` member of `PyObject`. The proper way to increase the reference count is through the use of the `Py_INCREF` macro or its `boost::python` equivalent `boost::python::incref`:

```
return boost::python::incref(obj.ptr());
```